# Members of child class are empty (polymorphism)

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following problem:
I have main executable program called `algatorc`. In this program, I have class called `TestCase`, `AbsAlgorithm` and `TestSetIterator`. End user must create new `algatorc` program and then inherits these three classes.

Let's say that end user creates project Sorting. He would end up with three classes called `SortingTestCase`, `SortingTestSetIterator` and `SortingAbsAlgorithm`.

So here is the thing. End user has a method `SortingTestSetIterator::get_current` and return type of this function is `TestCase*`. In this method, he creates instance of `SortingTestCase` and return this instance. So he actually returned child of `TestCase`. In my main program I save this pointer to `TestCase *t` (and no, I can't save it as SortingTestCase, because before runtime, I don't know the name of the project) and then I send this pointer to method `SortingAbsAlgorithm::init(TestCase* test_case)`. In this particulary method, end user will probably cast this object to his (`SortingTestCase`), and this is done like this:

```
sorting_test_case = dynamic_cast<SortingTestCase*>(test);
```

This `SortingTestCase` is derived from `TestCase` and has all members from parent class and two variables of his own: array and size. So when in init method I say

```
for (int i = 0; i<sorting_test_case->size; i++)
{
    std::cout << sorting_test_case[i] << std::endl;
}
```

then I get nothing. It seems like array is empty.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Edit:

```
class SortingAbsAlgorithm : public AbsAlgorithm 
{
private: 
        SortingTestCase *sorting_test_case;
public:
        bool init (TestCase *test) 
        {
                sorting_test_case = dynamic_cast<SortingTestCase*>(test);
                std::cout << "INIT ARRAY" << std::endl;
                for (int i = 0; i<sorting_test_case->size; i++)
                {
                        std::cout << sorting_test_case->array_to_sort[i] << " ";
                }
        }
};

class SortingTestCase : public TestCase
{
public:
    int size;
    int *array_to_sort;

    void init_array(int tab[], int size)
    {
        array_to_sort = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        {
            array_to_sort[i] = tab[i];
        }
    }
};

class SortingTestSetIterator : public TestSetIterator
{
private:
    std::string file_path;
    std::string test_file_name;
public:

    TestCase *get_current()
    {
        if (current_input_line.empty())
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        std::vector<std::string> fields;
        std::string token;
        std::stringstream str(current_input_line);
        while ( getline(str, token, ':') )
        {
            fields.push_back(token);
        }
        str.clear();

        if (fields.size() < 3)
        {
            report_invalid_data_format("to few fields");
            return nullptr;
        }

        std::string test_name = fields.at(0);
        int prob_size;
        try
        {
            prob_size = std::atoi(fields.at(1).c_str());
        } catch (...)
        {
            report_invalid_data_format("'n' is ot a number");
        }

        std::string group = fields.at(2);
        std::string test_id = "Test-" + std::to_string(line_number);
        EParameter *test_id_par = new EParameter("TestID", "Test identificator", test_id);
        EParameter *parameter1 = new EParameter("Test", "Test name", test_name);
        EParameter *parameter2 = new EParameter("N", "Number of elements", std::to_string(prob_size));
        EParameter *parameter3 = new EParameter("Group", "A name of a group of tests", group);

        SortingTestCase *t_case = new SortingTestCase();
        t_case->addParameter(*test_id_par);
        t_case->addParameter(*parameter1);
        t_case->addParameter(*parameter2);
        t_case->addParameter(*parameter3);

        int arr[prob_size];
        int i = 0;
        if (group == "INLINE")
        {
            if (fields.size() < 4)
            {
                report_invalid_data_format("to few fields");
                return nullptr;
            }
            std::vector<std::string> data;
            std::stringstream ss(fields.at(3));
            while (getline(ss, token, ' ') )
            {
                data.push_back(token);
            }

            if (data.size() != prob_size)
            {
                report_invalid_data_format("invalid number of inline data");
                return nullptr;
            }

            try
            {
                for (i = 0; i<prob_size; i++)
                {
                    arr[i] = std::atoi(data.at(i).c_str());
                }
            } catch (...)
            {
                report_invalid_data_format("invalid type of inline data - data " + std::to_string((i+1)));
                return nullptr;
            }
        }
        else if (group == "RND")
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
            for (i = 0; i<prob_size; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = rand() % prob_size + 1000;
            }
        }
        else if (group == "SORTED")
        {
            for (i = 0; i<prob_size; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = i;
            }
        }
        else if (group == "INVERSED")
        {
            for (i = 0; i<prob_size; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = prob_size - i;
            }
        }
        t_case->init_array(arr, prob_size);
        return t_case;
    }
};
```

This are end users classes. I create library out of this classes and I load them in my program via `dlopen` and `dlsym`. I get instance of classes like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
TestSetIterator * create_iterator_object() {
        return new SortingTestSetIterator;
}

void destroy_iterator_object(TestSetIterator* object) {
        delete object;
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
```

and then in my main program I load symbol `create_iterator_object`

```
create_it = (TestSetIterator* (*)())dlsym(handle, "create_iterator_object");
```

and then I say this:

```
TestSetIterator *it = (TestSetIterator*)create_it();
```

I can call it->get_current() which loads line from file to variable `curent_input_line`. So I do this:

```
TestCase *t_case = it->get_current();
```

and then I say

```
a->init(t_case)
```

a is here actually `SortingAbsAlgorithm` loaded exactly the same as TestSetIterator (ofcourse, different symbol) and is "saved" into `AbsAlgorithm a*`.

So when `a->init(t_case)` is called, then in this init end-user cast `t_case` this is type of `TestCase` to `SortingTestCase`. And when I want to print elements in array, array is empty.

Comment: 1st of all wrong asking without giving a MCVE here!

Comment: Many things could be wrong in your code. How can any one help you without seeing your code?

Comment: I wonder if you have an object slicing problem... but without seeing code, who knows.

Comment: I will provide source code then in next few minutes

Comment: @RyanP Yes, sounds so thoroughly:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: I've provided a source code. Unforunately I can't give you anything to compile because it would be too large :/ I can't break down this problem to few lines. Sorry. So, can any one of you see the problem?

Comment: @RyanP and others, I read that question and answers about slicing problem and I understand what is the problem here. But also...I'm not sure about this. In `SortingTestSetIterator::get_current()`, I create instance of `SortingTestCase` and then I return pointer to this instance. I believe this is wrong?Because that instance is local variable? But if is not, would it be ok if I return pointer to this `SortingTestCase` instance, then in my main program I will saved it to `TestCase` and then I will send it to `SortingAbsAlgorithm::init(TestCase*)`, then, there I will cast it to `SortingTestCase`?

Comment: Or am I imagine this all wrong?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Actualy I wasn't doing nothing wrong (except that pointer). I just forget to initialize size of array to class member variable. Thank you for help